# Why doesn't my PHP database backup script work?

Tags: php

When I manually run the output from print it works fine. However the actual program produces the following error:

sh: /mysqldump: No such file or directory

```
<?php

$backupFile = "backup/wordpress" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump -hlocalhost -uusername -ppassword dbname | gzip > $backupFile";
print $command;
system($command);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the full path in front of `mysqldump`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path to the mysqldump command line tool.

Entering...

```
which mysqldump
```

...from the shell will tell you the necessary path.